# How to get selected value on ng-click of button in Angular bootstrap-slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-slider

I have a scenario, in that I have to get the selected value of Bootstrap range slider on button click. Actually I have format() function in that I am getting the selected value in console. But I have to get that value on button click.

HTML:

```
 <slider ng-model="ctrl.value" ng-min="0" ng-disabled="ctrl.chk"
  ng-max="3" step="1" value="ctrl.value" ticks="ctrl.sliderTicks()" 
  formatter="ctrl.myFormatter" tooltip="always"></slider>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myFunc(ctrl.value)">save</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(value){
console.log(value);
}

this.myFormatter = function (value) {
    console.log('value %s', value);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `ng-model` of your slider is set to `ng-model="slider.value"`, this is this variable you are looking for in your button.

Change:

```
<button ... ng-click="myFunc(ctrl.value)">save</button>
```

To:

```
<button ... ng-click="myFunc(slider.value)">save</button>
```

Comment: sorry I updated the question,here ctrl.value is the default value for slider,but I need the current value of slider,by using format function I console the value.But,how to get in button.Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass it as argument, you already can got it in controller :

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.myFunc()">save</button>
```

in controller:

```
this.myFunc = function(){
  console.log(this.value);
}
```